# How to turn off Timed Publishing in google play console?

Tags: android, google-play

I just turn on Timed Publishing in google play console. But how should I turn it off and go back to Standard Publishing?

Because it may cause me the problem that every publish an app and has to click the Go Live button manually.

Please help, Thank you.

[Google Play Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9tau.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think after turn on Time Publishing that cannot be turn off until you upload a new apk/bundle then click Go Live button then Go Live button will only disappear and Time Publishing will appear again in Store presence -> store listing -> bottom of the page.

I will accept the answer if got any vote for this answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Does "go live" mean the app will be publicly available on Google Play?

Comment: Ya, correct. Example, u create a new release in Production and Start Rollout the new apk or new bundle, but there is still not yet publicly available on Google Play until u click Go Live.

Answer (score 0):

1)Go to your Play Console.

2)Select an app.

3)On the left menu, select Store presence.

4)At the bottom of your screen, go to the "Timed publishing" switch.

5)Review details about timed publishing, then click Turn off.

Comment: Hi kara, I can see the "Timed publishing" switch at the bottom of the page when I switch on. But when I want to turn off, i cant find the switch. You can view my image of Google Play Console at my question there.

Comment: Hi @JackyTeaw i too facing same problem in play console. You found any solution?

Comment: Hi @GopinathS, I have not found the solution. 

But after I manually click the "Go Live" Button, then the "Time Publishing" function is reset automatically.

Mean once you turn on the "Time Publishing", it need to click on "Go Live" button, then the "Time Publishing" only will turn off.